# When to use libmemcached in non-blocking mode?

Tags: memcached, libmemcached

I'm starting to integrate libmemcached into my application and reading the documentation, there is a non-blocking mode flag. After a quick google, there seems to be a performance advantage to non blocking mode, but are there any disadvantages to running libmemcached in non blocking mode?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are.  The disadvantage would only arise if you needed to ENSURE that the written value actually was written to memcached and did not fail.  For example - you're using memcached to store a counter variable which has a sentinel that checks to see if the counter has reached a certain value before performing an operation.

In blocking mode - the memcached client will wait to get a write success response from memcached before proceeding and produce an error if it fails. This way you know the counter was updated. If you tell it to write in non-blocking mode, the client sends the request to increment the counter, but never waits to ensure that it really occurred.  Because it doesn't wait, you code execution after the call resumes more quickly, but with the uncertainty of not knowing for sure the counter was ever incremented.

However, since memcached values are destroyed on a service restart (think system crash) you can't ever really be sure a value will be there. Also, with low-memory pruning you also cannot ever be sure the value is 100% correct as it may get pruned by the LRU algorithm - you'd need persistent storage to alleviate this uncertainty.

Given this inherent uncertainty, many people use non-blocking mode to get the performance gain because they can't ever be totally certain the counter value in memcached isn't reset/innacurate anyway, so why not get some performance for the tradeoff.

Hope this clarifies the issue.  As a side note - MongoDB has non-blocking writes in persistent storage - which while awesome in its flexibility, gives people using non-blocking mode more of a false sense of security that the write will always succeed...

R